# PHP array posición key desconocida

Tags: php, array

Tengo esta instrucción

```
foreach ($array as $clave => $valor) {}
```

y los voy colocando dentro de una array.

Ahora bien, el problema es que cuando intento recorrer el array, no conozco los $clave para que me devuelva un resultado.

Si voy a iterar, por ejemplo la primera posición, uno puede pensar "array_key_first" o "array_key_last", ¿pero si queremos la posición en concreto?, por ejemplo la 3, no podemos hacer array[2], es un Undefined offset.

¿Hay alguna forma de no hacerle un "reset" a las key positions de la array y puedar iterar la posición que quieras?
Por favor, pediría que no implementarais una array 2d, no tendría sentido.

Los datos que tengo son:

```
array["Especie1"] = algo;
array["Valor2"] = algo; 
array["View2"] = algo;
array["Zeppelin2"] = algo;
```

Pero el id de indexación texto ['no lo conozco, se va insertando en el bucle']
El problema de esto, es que si quiero acceder directamente a la posición 3, 7 o cualquier otro, tengo que hacer un bucle.

Hay alguna instrucción que te permita array[0]  llegar a  array["Especie1"] = algo?

Como dije, array_key_first y array_key_fast cumplen con esa condición, pero solo es el primer ID y el último.

Según el ejemplo pasado:

```
array_key_first -> devolvería -> array["Especie1"] = algo;
array_key_last -> devolvería -> array["Zeppelin2"] = algo;
```

La solución que he encontrado es tener 2 arrays, una con índices y la otra con keys. Porqué voy a trabajar con todos los datos. Es demasiado "ugly" des de mi punto de vista, porqué acostumbro a ser bastante purista y esto es como escupir en el proyecto.

Comment: Por favor, podrías colocar un ejemplo de tu variable array? Dicho así no tiene mucho sentido porque un array siempre tiene índices, luego siempre podrías conocer el valor de $clave.

Comment: Pero el índice no es un número, es decir, es algo tal que array["Especie1"] = algo, array["Valor2"] = algo, array["View2"] = algo. Por tanto, yo no puedo decir quién es el primero, el segundo, el tercer diciendo [0],[1].... porqué sus ID son texto. Desconozco si hay una forma de ir a por el 4, sin tener que hacer un bucle, tal y como lo hace array_key_first / array_key_last

Comment: Si necesitas los valores posicionales puedes hacer `$arr_temp = array_values($tu_array);` y luego `$n_esimo_valor = $arr_tmp[$n];` con $n = al número de posición que deseas contando desde 0 para el primero ver:[array_values](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-values)

Comment: Parece una solución bastante acurada, no me gusta mucho pero soluciona el problema. Publica el resultado y marcaré como resuelto. Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No es necesario el uso de ciclos ni declarar otras variables, [`array_values()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-values.php) te devuelve un arreglo con índices numéricos.

```
<?php

$array = [
    'Especie1' => 'Contenido Especie1',
    'Valor2' => 'Contenido Valor2',
    'View2' => 'Contenido View2',
    'Zeppelin2' => 'Contenido Zeppelin2'
];
echo array_values($array)[2];  // Contenido View2
```

Si solo vas a extraer un elemento, con esto es suficiente, de lo contrario, crea una variable adicional, como bien te sugirió **quevedo** en su comentario.

Answer (score 1):

Los arrays siempre tienen índices numéricos, aunque no se vean.

Si he entendido bien, tu array se parecería a esto:

```
$mArray=array(
                array("Especie1" => "Valor para Especie1"), 
                array("Valor2" => "Valor para Valor2"), 
                array("View2" => "Valor para View2") 
            );
```

Pues en ese array hay tres índices: `0`, `1` y `2`.

Hagamos una prueba:

```
#Elemento que está en segunda posición del array
var_dump($mArray[1]);
```

**Salida:**

```
array(1) {
  ["Valor2"]=>
  string(17) "Valor para Valor2"
}
```

Igualmente puedes obtener el valor directamente con algo como:

```
echo $mArray[1]["Valor2"];
```

**Salida:**

```
Valor para Valor2
```

---

Si los arrays no están asociados en uno solo (son arrays separados uno de otro), puedes unirlos en uno sólo mediante `array_merge()`, pero poniendo cada array entre `[]`, así, `array_merge` te los combinará como sub-arrays, cada uno con su índice.

Por ejemplo:

```
$a1=array("Especie1" => "Valor para Especie1"); 
$a2=array("Valor2" => "Valor para Valor2"); 
$a3=array("View2" => "Valor para View2"); 

$mArray=array_merge([$a1],[$a2],[$a3]);

var_dump($mArray);
```

**Salida:**

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Especie1"]=>
    string(19) "Valor para Especie1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Valor2"]=>
    string(17) "Valor para Valor2"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    ["View2"]=>
    string(16) "Valor para View2"
  }
}


echo $mArray[1]["Valor2"];
```

**Salida:**

```
Valor para Valor2
```